# Wpf ComboBox throws exception on combobox in windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I made a WPF application (Framework 4.5) on Windows 8 which uses usual comboboxes and some other controls. The problem I am facing is that it crashes on Windows 7:

```
A first chance exception of type System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox' threw an exception.'
```

Here is my XAML for combobox:

```
 <ComboBox Name="bloodGroupList" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"
         SelectedIndex="{Binding Patient.BloodGroup, Converter={StaticResource StrToBlood}, Mode=TwoWay}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditing}"
         VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5.5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
         BorderThickness="0" Height="22" TabIndex="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A+" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A-" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="B+" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="B-" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="O+" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="O-" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="AB+" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="AB-" />
</ComboBox>
```

I read on some blog to run this fix `NDP45-KB2750147-x64` but it says:

> Software Update KB2750147 Installation Wizard does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer. Please click the link below for more details.

Comment: Can you show the XAML code that you have used to define the combobox?

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt it lately?  Have you tried it on the windows 8 machine you wrote it on without the debugger?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Code is added now

Comment: @FelixCastor yes I have done tat plus  it works fine on every windows 8 machine I have tried on but crashes on windows 7

Comment: How is your converter defined?

Comment: @Even if I remove every thing and just do it like following it gives me error:<ComboBox Name="bloodGroupList" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"
        >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A+" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="A-" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="B+" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="B-" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="O+" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="O-" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="AB+" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="AB-" />
</ComboBox>

Comment: Does it give the error in the designer or during execution? Sometimes the designer crashes but this doesn't mean it wouldn't work at runtime. Also check the version of the assembly dependencies. If there is a mismatch this can lead to crashes.

Comment: it gives error on run time. How to check version assembly dependencies, can you please guide me ?

Comment: Do the windows 7 machines have .net 4.5 installed?

Comment: I am also facing same issue @SafiMustafa

Answer (score 0):

I put this in the `App.xaml.cs` file to get the full stack trace. This might be a useful way for you to troubleshoot problems.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // All unhandled exceptions come here. A stacktrace is saved as a text file with date and time.

        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(e.Exception);
        string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-') + " errors.txt";
        fileName = @"C:\Users\Public\" + fileName;
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Critical Error. Closing program.\nStacktrace can be found:" + fileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (var strWrite = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                strWrite.Write(st.ToString());
            }
        }

        if (MainWindow != null)
        {
            MainWindow.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't come here on that exception